# Internet Explorer doesn't detect screen size correctly in case of dual monitors

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, screen-resolution, multiple-monitors

I noticed that Internet Explorer 10 doesn't show the correct screen size in case of dual monitors. It always takes the screen size of your `primary monitor`.

Example: If you open [this page](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/newtech3.shtml) which calculates your screen size and you've dual monitors then you'll notice that it will not work correctly in Internet Explorer, whereas it works fine in FF and Google Chrome.

Is there any workaround to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure it's ie10 all around, not something more so with the site? How are you detecting, or planning to detect screen size? I haven't used ie10 yet, but I would assume responsive CSS works well in it, and would relate to the scaling of your browser.

Comment: This [connect bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/790582/ie-10-javascript-reporting-incorrect-screen-size-on-multi-monitor-setup) seems related, but was closed as unreproducable

Comment: Typical Microsoft. People have reported this bug in IE8, IE9 and IE10. But every time they ignore it. Maybe they don't have a solution for that, or something else, IDK.

Comment: What is your exact question?  Are you trying to resolve the issue with the page (and therefore do you own the page?), are you asking for a way to reliably detect the usable size of the browser rendering area, or are you asking for a way to detect the size of the screen in a way that has nothing to do with the browser rendering area?

Comment: @Chankey. Were you able to find a solution for that problem?

Comment: @Mark: No, I did not find any solution.

Comment: This happens in IE11 as well.  Unfortunately, it is a bug, which will probably never be fixed.

Comment: It's also happening in Firefox 96.0.3